# What does the word 'X' GB Memory refers to in the App Service Plan Pricing Tiers Image?

Tags: azure-app-service-plans

[image: ASP Specs]

In every model of App Service Plan, there is 1 word called 1.75 GB, 3.5GB, 7GB, 14 GB Memory, etc.

Is that refer to RAM of the that VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes! It's similar to a provisioned RAM on a VM**.

When upgrading to the Premium App Service Plan, it will show how many CPU Cores are along with the RAM.

Whatever you mentioned 1.75 GB, 3.5 GB, and 7 GB belong to RAM in **Standard App Service Plan**!

**Reference**: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/